How to find non reducible fractions more efficently(code keeps timing out)
I'm trying to find the non-reducible 0-1 fractions for a number passed as an argument in my function.
I was able to do this but my code keeps timing out for large numbers. Please help
function properFractions(n) {
  function gcd(a, b) {
    if (a == 0) return b;
    return gcd(b % a, a);
  }

  let result = 0;

  if (n === 1) {
    return result;
  } else if (n > 1) {
    for (let i = 1; i < n; i++) if (gcd(i, n) === 1) result++;
    return result;
  }
}


How large is large? I suspect you're exceeding the precision of JavaScript integers.

BTW, gcd(1, x) is always 1. So you could initialize result = 1 and start with i=2

Well it works for larger numbers in codewars but still keeps timing out. Should I refactor for BigInt as well?

There's an optimization you can make: If n or i is prime, all fractions involving it are irreducible. So if you have a table of all prime up to n, you can skip lots of calls to gcd

Can you show me in code please. I'm still kind of new to this

if (isPrime(n)) return n

if (isPrime(i) || gcd(i, n) ==1) result++;

now you just need to write isPrime. Use Sieve of Eratosthenese to construct all the primes up to n.

This challenge really asks you to write Euler's totient function. Wikipedia gives some formulas to calculate it, like the product formula:


where the product is over the distinct prime numbers dividing .

To speed up the collection of prime factors, you could memoize primes numbers. This might not be necessary to pass the actual tests on CodeWars, but it does provide better running times.
Here is a possible way to do that:


const primes = [2, 3]; // Memoization of primes starts with these

function loadPrimes(n) {
    // Extend list of primes until the given value
    for (let p = primes[primes.length - 1] + 2; p <= n; p+=2) {
        const sq = Math.sqrt(p);
        for (const prime of primes) {
            if (prime > sq) {
                primes.push(p);
                break;
            }
            if (p % prime == 0) break;
        }
    }
}

function properFractions(n) {
    if (n == 1) return 0;
    let result = n;
    const sq = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(n));
    loadPrimes(sq); // Ensure we have enough primes
    for (const prime of primes) {
        if (prime > sq) break;
        if (n % prime == 0) {
            n /= prime;
            result = result * (prime - 1) / prime;
            while (n % prime == 0) {
                n /= prime;
            }
        }
    }
    if (n > 1) { // is prime
        result = result * (n - 1) / n;
    }
    return result;
}

// Example run
console.log(properFractions(5890320000)); // 1555200000



